# I get the error $(...).modal is not a function even though bootstrap is imported after jQuery how can i fix this (using npm versions)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, electron

I did extensive research before posting this issue and feel I have exhausted the online documentation and Stack Overflow.

My issue:

I'm using the npm versions of bootstrap with the tempus dominus date time picker script and get the error $(...).modal is not a function even though jQuery is imported before bootstrap and then used to actually import bootstrap in the backend like so:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer
const jQuery = require('jQuery');
const $ = require('jQuery');
require('popper.js')
const moment = require('moment')
$(document).ready(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send('page-ready');

    moment().format();
    $.getScript("./js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js", function() {

      $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
        });
      });

      $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
      });
      });

    })
    require("bootstrap")
});
```

Things i've tried:

So after some research i discovered it might be because jQuery was imported twice to make another js script work correctly so i fixed this by changing my code to:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer
const jQuery = require('jQuery');
const $ = jQuery.noConflict();
require('popper.js')
const moment = require('moment')
$(document).ready(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send('page-ready');

    moment().format();
    $.getScript("./js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js", function() {

      $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
        });
      });

      $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
      });
      });

    })
    require("bootstrap")
});
```

The code where the modal is called:

```
ipcRenderer.on("edit-self-result", (event, arg) => {
  if (arg == false) {
    $('#editMemberModal').modal('toggle');
    document.getElementById("userTypeEdit").value = usertype
    document.getElementById("usernameEdit").value = username
    document.getElementById("emailEdit").value = email
  }
})
```

Comment: What if you put `require("bootstrap")` outside the doc ready?  Could it be that the ipcRenderer is firing before bootstrap has loaded?

Comment: it shouldn't be as it fires when i press a button which gets data from the backed and sends it to the front end so it shouldn't be firing too early but i tried what you suggested and it made no difference

Comment: Does `$().modal()` work anywhere else on your page?  Does any other bootstrap js (core bootstrap, not 3rd party addons) work? Maybe you have a version of bootstrap that doesn't include modal?

Comment: `$(...).modal(...)` doesn't work anywhere else on my page and im not sure if any other bootstrap js works but i can confirm it is definitely being imported successfully: https://imgur.com/a/y6SFVH7

Comment: Your screenshot also shows jquery loaded twice.  Check the network tab to ensure jquery isn't being (re-)loaded *after* bootstrap, as that would remove bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Okay so i looked into what you said and realized that this is caused by code needed to be run before i load the time picker as other wise i get issues because instead of the time picker using $ to check for jQuery it uses the word jQuery but my code is this so it shouldn't be causing an issue: https://imgur.com/a/8c6Vl4c

Comment: I found a solution!

Comment: 2 versions of jQuery is never a good idea.

Comment: I don't have 2 and the only reason it seems to load twice is because of the 2 constants I have to give to jQuery but my answer below has fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple hours of pulling my hair out, I managed to get a working solution I don't know why this fixes it but if anyone wants to alter this answer to explain why this works go ahead.

But I changed my code from this:

```
const jQuery = require('jQuery');
const $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

To this:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
global.$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Should you try this.

```
$("..")[0].modal
```

Comment: Hi there I'm afraid this has no effect and i still get the same issue